# MongoDB on machine or MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, deployment, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-atlas

Suppose I want to host my e-commerce website on GCP/AWS/Digitalocean. I am using MongoDB as database.
Then which will be better?

1. Installing mongodb on the remote machine (GCP/AWS/Digitalocean)

   **or**
2. Using MongoDB Atlas for deploying, managing the database
   Can you mention the pros and cons of both and in which situation I should use these methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a really tricky question to answer as every other person will have a different opinion, ill try to answer based on my own experience (aws ec2 instances).

Atlas vs EC2 cons:

1. I would say the number one "con" of atlas is the cost, it is far more expensive than running your own ec2 (at-least at my scale which around 1TB of data), this varies according to amount of data, instances size, backup routine and more.
2. you have less "control", clearly you wont be able to access the actual server on which the instance is running on.

Pros:

1. you have less "control", matching argument 2 in the cons this can be seen as a pro, you don't have to maintain the server and all that comes with it. 
   do your own math on wether this is a pro or not.

I'm gonna stop here as i can keep listing endless minor differences that are at the end of the day mostly opinion oriented.

I would say though (again based on my own experience) that atlas is great, i would greatly consider using it especially if the following conditions are met:

1. i don't have a person experienced with aws ec2 instances on my team. (this will cause you to spend alot of time just starting out).
2. small scale, atlas cost is not that high on small scale and it gives you alot of power and saves you some headaches allowing you to push your product foward.

Comment: Hey I had the same question. Can you let us know what you meant by "small scale"? What kind of numbers are you talking about?

Comment: It all depends on how much money you have to spend on this, but for me small scale is a dataset of a few milion documents, no more than let's say 10-20 gigabytes